# Equivalent of Matlab's fread() 'float64' in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, fread

I have a binary file which I'm able to open in MATLAB, but unable to open in Python.  The binary file is encoded as a 'double float,' thus read by MATLAB with the following line:

```
fread(fopen(fileName), 'float64');
```

In Python, I'm not really sure how to replicate this line.  I thought using Numpy would be a good place to start, so I tried the following lines, but didn't get the output I expected. There are 6 numbers in each line, I only got the first one and a single 'NaN.'

```
from numpy import * 
f = open('filename', 'rb') 
a = fromfile(f, double64, 10)
print a
```

Any help on this would be extremely appreciated; I've posted both the binary and the MATLAB parsed files in the comments below.  I don't need to use Numpy specifically either, I'm open to any Python based solution. Thank you.

Comment: "There are 6 numbers in each line" -- "line"?  Are they ASCII-encoded or IEEE-float encoded?

Comment: Link for the data file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2mggkyyzlpcrs31/TEMPO3.2F-0215_s00116.dat

Comment: Link for the MATLAB parsed file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nk8mm40uovgeixu/TEMPO3.2F-0215_s00116.csv

Comment: can it be the endianness that scews it up? (i had it before that that was the reason my data didnt make any sense with numpy.fromfile)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every second value is `nan` so this might be some delimiter. Also, the values in the file are column-first. The following script reads in the data, throws away the NaN entries, manipulates the array into the correct shape, and outputs a CSV file which is identical to the one you posted:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

# Pull in all the raw data.
with open('TEMPO3.2F-0215_s00116.dat', 'rb') as f:
    raw = np.fromfile(f, np.float64)

# Throw away the nan entries.
raw = raw[1::2]

# Check its a multiple of six so we can reshape it.
if raw.size % 6:
    raise ValueError("Data size not multiple of six.")

# Reshape and take the transpose to manipulate it into the
# same shape as your CSV. The conversion to integer is also
# so the CSV file is the same.
data = raw.reshape((6, raw.size/6)).T.astype('int')

# Dump it out to a CSV.
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(data)
```

**Edit**: Updated version with changes suggested by [jorgeca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191119/jorgeca):

```
import csv
import numpy as np

# Pull in all the raw data.
raw = np.fromfile('TEMPO3.2F-0215_s00116.dat', np.float64)

# Throw away the nan entries.
raw = raw[1::2]

# Reshape and take the transpose to manipulate it into the
# same shape as your CSV. The conversion to integer is also
# so the CSV file is the same.
data = raw.reshape((6, -1)).T.astype('int')

# Dump it out to a CSV.
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(data)
```

Comment: For added confusion to anybody maintaining your code, you could always read the data as `complex128` and then call `np.imag()` to take the values from the imaginary parts...

Comment: ...and no, that was not a serious suggestion :P.

Comment: Nice answer! A couple of comments that you probably know, but I think are interesting: `np.fromfile` accepts a file name, so you don't have to wrap it in a `with...` block; `.reshape` raises a ValueError if it can't do it, so in the spirit of [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) the error checking could be removed (it'll fail anyway); `.reshape` accepts -1 as a "wild card" dimension.

Comment: @Blair, Thank you so much! Your solution worked like a charm! Just out of curiosity, do you happen to know of any resources I could read to avoid asking similar questions in the future?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Anish - not offhand. I don't think I've read much other than the basic NumPy tutorial. The rest is just searching the documentation / internet and playing around to see what works.

Answer (score 4):

There is a delimiter between your data values producing alternating data and NaN on reading, for instance in matlab:

```
 NaN
2134
 NaN
2129
 NaN
2128
....
1678
```

and with numpy:

```
[   nan  2134.    nan ...,  1681.    nan  1678.]
```

I get the same input using the code you posted either with Matlab or numpy(1.7). Note that the data is read from your dat file column-wise, not row-wise according to the pattern in your csv file.

To get ALL of the data in numpy try

```
a = fromfile(file=f, dtype=float64, count=-1)
```